# Create new column from existing dataframe column with condition

Tags: python, pandas, list, dictionary, search

GroupID column has two values one alphanumeric and other is numeric, I want use alphanumeric part of column to create new column, with some condition like if alphanumeric is present in o_dict then it should return value else it should just return "NOT IN DIC"

```
GroupID
0   ad32s;#1214;#rf343;#4343
1   wd435;#6464;#ed532;#5454
2   av345e:#3132
3   ok132d;#8897
4   tn123h;#0980
5   as845;#657;#un567t;#456;#qw147;#123
6   ok132d;#8897
7   as845;#657;#un567t;#456;#qw147;#123
8   wd435;#6464;#ed532;#5454

o_dict= {"ad32s":"rupesh","ed532":"Frank","dr501u":"David","ok132d":"Ripal",
         "qw147":"ilesh","av345e":'carls'}
```

below is my code:

```
def function01(row):
o_dict= {"ad32s":"rupesh","ed532":"Frank","dr501u":"David","ok132d":"Ripal","qw147":"ilesh","av345e":'carls'}
    if element.isalnum():
        if element in o_dict:
            return owner_dict[element]
        else:
            return "NOT IN DIC"
    else:
        continue
df['New_column'] = df.apply(lambda x: function01(x), axis=1)
```

This code works if the alphanumeric value is at first position but does not work if it is at 3 or 5 position. It works for row 0,2,3,4 6, but does not work for 1,5,7,8.

O/p should have two columns with values from dict which matched with groupid else it should be populated with  "NOT IN DIC".

I not sure what i can do now, is there another approach to get this values ?
is there any search function which can be used to search for this values ??

Thanks for helping :)

Comment: Please do NOT post your data as image, you can copy and paste the printed dataframe.

Comment: Also make sure to include your expected output.

Comment: Click here to [edit].

Answer (score 0):

I found that in my code for-loop was only working for first value in list and it was populating "NOT IN DIC" without checking for other values. I have made below changes now and I am getting expected output.

```
def function01(row):
o_dict= {"ad32s":"rupesh","ed532":"Frank","dr501u":"David","ok132d":"Ripal","qw147":"ilesh","av345e":'carls'}
listA = row['Assigned'].split(";#")
listB = [i for i in listA if i.isdigit()==False]
for element in listA:
    if element in owner_dict:
        return owner_dict[element]
    else:
        continue    
return "NOT IN DIC"

df['New_column'] = df.apply(lambda x: function01(x), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

you may want to use `numpy.select`

```
    import numpy
    import pandas

    d = {
        "GroupID": [
            "ad32s;#1214;#rf343;#4343",
            "wd435;#6464;#ed532;#5454",
            "av345e:#3132",
            "ok132d;#8897",
            "tn123h;#0980",
            "as845;#657;#un567t;#456;#qw147;#123",
            "ok132d;#8897",
            "as845;#657;#un567t;#456;#qw147;#123",
            "wd435;#6464;#ed532;#5454",
        ]
    }

    o_dict = {
        "ad32s": "rupesh",
        "ed532": "Frank",
        "dr501u": "David",
        "ok132d": "Ripal",
        "qw147": "ilesh",
        "av345e": "carls",
    }

    df = pandas.DataFrame.from_dict(d)

    values = []
    def fn(k):
        values.append(o_dict[k])
        return df["GroupID"].str.find(k) != -1
    conditions = list(map(fn, o_dict))

    df["New_column"] = numpy.select(conditions, values, default="NOT IN DIC")
    print(df)
```